# Transit Visa for Malaysia

Tags: transit-visas, kul

I'm traveling from Macao to India with Air Asia and have an 8-hour transit in Kuala Lumpur.

I do not plan to leave the airport, but I'm wondering if I need a transit visa for Malaysia.

Comment: You may also want to amend the question title to include the transit location as well.

Comment: @choster - Your edits have changed the character of this question.  The OPs original verbiage said "airasia fly through" (actually branded as "AirAsia Fly-Thru") which is crucial to this question, as it is a program that allows passengers to check their bags through and not claim them in KUL.  You and Burhan kind of went overboard editing this question.

Comment: @Tom Ah,  sorry,  I was not familiar with that offering, but this is exactly why conventional orthography and diction is so important online. A capital letter, and I would have Googled.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the original verbiage of your question, if you are using AirAsia's Fly-Thru service, then you can remain airside and not enter the country.

If you are not using the Fly-Thru service, then you will need to enter the country, claim your checked bags and then check in for the second flight, as AirAsia is primarily a point to point carrier (except fares with Fly-Thru).  What visa may be required in this case is solely dependent on your nationality, which we don't know at the moment.

Comment: AirAsia's Fly-Thru service applies only to its own flights and all their flights go via KLIA2.  As far as I know, there is no way to travel between KLIA1 and KILA2 while remaining "airside", you have to clear immigration.

Comment: Fly-Thru is a relatively new offering by AirAsia (last couple of years) and is available now when transiting through either KUL or DMK (Bangkok).